# Jni4net with custom Java Classes or Jar

Tags: java, c#, .net, jar, jni4net

I saw a lot of examples on how to use primitive java classes in .NET, but how I can use my own Jar in .NET? Until now I could do this by reflection, but because I have a method with parameters File[] and String[] and jni4net doesn't have a definition for class of this (i.e. File[].class), I cannot invoke them.

I couldn't find a step by step tutorial on how I can do this. I tried with generateProxies.cmd, but I still cannot make it work.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You might try a slightly different approach: rather than trying to use a Java array, use a .net array of Java File objects? or even a c# list, for example List<File.class>  (paraphrasing here, my VS2010 is updating so cannot access my environment to check what this would be exactly).  Let me know if you need more info, and I will post an actual answer anyway once I get access to my Dev Environment. :)